# How do I add a python3 kernel to my jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I installed jupyter notebook along with anaconda python as the only python on my PC (Windows 10). However I recently installed python 3.6.2 and I wonder if I can somehow add it to jupyter so as I can use them changeably.

I remember having both on my other machine when I installed python first and then after that I installed the whole anaconda package with the jupyter notebook (so I had python 3 and python(conda) option for kernels).

So how can I add to jupyter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To install a Jupyter kernel for a different version of Python, run:

```
conda create -n py36 'python=3.6' ipykernel  # Replace `3.6` with desired version
```

To enable the newly installed Jupyter kernel in all conda environments, run:

```
source activate py36
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

Now, when you start Jupyter from your root environment, you will have the option to choose a different Python kernel when you click on 'Kernel -> Change kernel':

```
source deactivate
jupyter notebook
```

For more info, see [Installing the IPython kernel](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html).

Comment: I also installed nb_conda so I could switch in between those kernels in the notebook: ``conda install nb_conda``

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just find where the script `jupyter-notebook` resides, for example `~/.local/bin` if you installed it locally.

Then just edit the first line to:   `#!/usr/bin/python3` will be fine.